# Typescript .find for Custom Array

Tags: typescript, angular8

I am trying to use .find method but I am getting undefined.

```
const ValidationMsg = '[{        "enum": "RequiredInformationMissing",        "code": 101,        
"title": "Required information not provided",        "message": "The following information is needed 
to complete :" },    {        "enum": "RequiredInformationMissing_Details",        "code": 102,        
"title": "Required information not provided",        "message": "The following information is needed 
to complete the :"    }]';

const validationErrors : Array<ValidationError> = JSON.parse(ValidationMsg);
const x = validationErrors.find(ve => ve.code === (101 as number));

export class ValidationError {    
 code: number;
 message: string;
}
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Thanks,
Sajesh

Comment: You are calling an object property with `this.` but `validationErrors` is a `const` variable defined one line above. Try `const x = validationErrors.find(ve => ve.code === (101 as number));`

Comment: `Array<ValidationError>[]` is an array or arrays, and does not represent your data. After cleaning up the string, changing the type, and removing the `this`, I do get a value from the find via Typescript Playground (url link is too long to post in a comment).

Comment: Your code doesn't compile: validationErrors is of type `Array<ValidationError>[]` instead of `Array<ValidationError>`, your JSON is invalid, your string literal is not valid TypeScript. Fix all the compilation errors and use valid JSON, and the code will run fine. Note that 101 as number is redundant: 101 is a number.

Answer (score 1):

> Try this.

const x = validationErrors.filter(ve => ve.code === (101 as number))[0];

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, as you all pointed out correctly the issue was due to nested Arrays declaration.